# How to iterate over unicode characters in C++?

Tags: c++, unicode, wstring

I know that to get a unicode character in C++ I can do:

```
std::wstring str = L"\u4FF0";
```

However, what if I want to get all the characters in the range 4FF0 to 5FF0? Is it possible to dynamically build a unicode character? What I have in mind is something like this pseudo-code:

```
for (int i = 20464; i < 24560; i++ { // From 4FF0 to 5FF0
    std::wstring str = L"\u" + hexa(i); // build the unicode character
    // do something with str
}
```

How would I do that in C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wchar_t type held within a wstring is an integer type, so you can use it directly:

```
for (wchar_t c = 0x4ff0;  c <= 0x5ff0;  ++c) {
    std::wstring str(1, c);
    // do something with str
}
```

Be careful trying to do this with characters above 0xffff, since depending on the platform (e.g. Windows) they will not fit into a wchar_t.

If for example you wanted to see the [Emoticon block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block)) in a string, you can create surrogate pairs:

```
std::wstring str;
for (int c = 0x1f600; c <= 0x1f64f; ++c) {
    if (c <= 0xffff || sizeof(wchar_t) > 2)
        str.append(1, (wchar_t)c);
    else {
        str.append(1, (wchar_t)(0xd800 | ((c - 0x10000) >> 10)));
        str.append(1, (wchar_t)(0xdc00 | ((c - 0x10000) & 0x3ff)));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Captain Giraffe, if your wchar_t type is larger than 16 bits it will be no problem. Otherwise you have to break it into two wchar_t characters according to the [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-16) rules.

Comment: If today was yesterday the type would have been called byte, not char =) Also "word" springs to mind

Comment: there is no problem with 0xffff.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe an anonymous downvote today convinced me to add the code for the higher codepoints.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot increment over Unicode characters as if it is an array, some characters are build up out of multiple 'char's (UTF-8) and multiple 'WCHAR's (UTF-16) that's because of the diacritics etc. If you're really serious about this stuff you should use an API like UniScribe or ICU.

Some resources to read:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character

http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=UnicodeNames#4d2aa980

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374126.aspx

Comment: The first statement is correct; the reasons not. UTF-8 and UTF-16 are encodings, and are orthogonal to code points. Diacritics are also code points, so those are independent of UTF-8 and -16 too

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
for (std::wstring::value_type i(0x4ff0); i <= 0x5ff0; ++i)
{
    std::wstring str(1, i);
}
```

Note that the code has not been tested, so it may not compile as-is.

Also, given the platform you are working on a `wstring`'s character unit may be 2, 4, or N bytes wide- so be intentional about how you use it.

Comment: replace `char_type` with `value_type` and it will compile.